# General Party Secretary of the CCP, Xi Jinping, called for the revival of the Chinese spirit

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas, definite-articles

> General Party Secretary of the CCP, Xi Jinping, called for the revival of the Chinese spirit.

I think it's ungrammatical, and *the* is required before *general*, or the commas must be omitted. Do experts here agree?

Comment: No, it is perfectly fine as it is, although adding ‘the’ would not be wrong, either. Titles like “General Party Secretary” do not necessarily need the article, even if you have “of the CCP” there as well.

Comment: My apologies: I accidentally voted to close on this question instead of one I had open in another tab.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Malvolio is right. As written the commas should be removed. If "The" were added, the commas would not be a problem.

Comment: @StoneyB Wasn't reverse closevote just implemented?

Comment: @MετάEd I didn't know that - thanks. Retracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is wrong.

Either the name Xi Jinping is meant as an [appositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) and the subject of the sentence is General Party Secretary or Xi Jinping is the subject and General Party Secretary is his title.

An appositive, like a lot of phrases, can be deleted without affecting the structure of the rest of the sentence.  How does the following look to you?

> General Party Secretary called for the revival of the Chinese spirit.

Now the need for *the* is more obvious.

If Xi Jinping is the subject, then yes, what are those vagrant commas doing there?

I think it may be the sheer volume of words that's confusing people.  Let's say the Secretary's name is Bob, and just call him Secretary, and all he does is call.

> Secretary, Bob, called.

No, any native English speaker would write either "The Secretary, Bob, called." or "Secretary Bob called."

Comment: Your answer redefines the question. You can not remove parts of a sentence and expect it to work the same way. The sentence "US President, Barack Obama, says..." is not the same as "US President says". No one is confused by the "sheer volume of words". You're confused by the words you've chosen to remove.

Comment: What's wrong with saying "Secretary Bob called" anyway?

Comment: @CarlSmith -- yes, in fact, one can remove phrases and expect the syntactical significance of the sentences to remain.  `US President, Barack Obama, says...` may have more detail than `US President says...` but they are equally incorrect.  And `Secretary Bob called` is listed as one of the correct alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is perfect. Using *the* before General is also okay. I think the commas cannot be omitted; else the secretary's name cannot be distinguished. It would seem as if he is the secretary of the party/section/office (whatever you are referring to) which is known as  *CCP Xi Jinping*.

Comment: Shaona, but if one italicizes Xi Jinping, are the parenthetical commas still required?

Comment: If "Xi Jinping" is italicized, it may mean that the CCP is called Xi Jinping. Unless a person is already aware of the context user48175 is referring to, a reader may have some confusion. The comma clearly brings out that the secretary's name is Xi Jinping, without any further doubt.

Comment: Shaona, thank you; and, surely, your last comment deserves a great +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sentence is fine as it is. The first part, 'General Party Secretary of the CCP', is a title, so it doesn't need the word *the* in front of it. You can start a sentence with a title like that.

US President, Barack Obama, called for...

**Note:** Janus' comment on the question says the same thing, and it's slightly more precise. This answer was a few minutes late. Give any votes to Janus.